# Customize OOB Publishing/Approval Workflow with Schedule

Tags: workflow, publishing, schedule

I have the following problem. I would like to customize the OOB publishing/content approval workflow with a schedule date. So the OOB workflow has the following functionality: Anyone edit or add a page and approvers can click on "Approve it" and the page will publish. I would like to customize the workflow so that anyone edit or add a page and approvers get a new task to edit a "Publishing Date". On this date the page should be publishing automatically.

So my idea was to customize the OOB workflow and add a new task to get the publishing date form the approvers. That's no problem, but the OOB workflow does not depend on this date. If I click on "Approve it" it is it does not matter what I edit in the publishing date field. I add a task to pause the workflow until this date but the button "Approve it" is still present and the page can be publish before this date. Anyone has an idea?